# What is the diplomatic record on President Sadat's 1971 peace offer to Israel?

Tags: israel, egypt, palestine

I have seen a lot of talk in the Israel-Palestine debate about the 1971 peace offer, but I can't find any original sources on it. Even Wikipedia's brief paragraph about it says "citation needed."

What is the diplomatic record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question:** What is the diplomatic record on President Sadat's 1971 Peace Offer to Israel?

I'm not sure what you mean about diplomatic record, but here is what I found.

- **[Sadat Peace Initiative of 1971 - English Text](https://ecf.org.il/media_items/542)**

  > A speech made by Egyptian President Anwar Sadat on 3 February 1971. To that end, he accepted the UN Secretary-General's appeal to extend the ceasefire which ended the War of Attrition, and called on Israel to redeploy its forces away from the Suez Canal, while Egypt would reopen it to international navigation. … This in turn will initiate the implementation of UN Security Council Resolution 242 and the withdrawal of Israel back to pre-1967 lines.
- **[Israel-Egypt Ceasefire Agreement - Text - English (1970)](https://ecf.org.il/media_items/271)**
- **[Israel-Egypt Ceasefire Agreement - Text - Hebrew (1970)](https://ecf.org.il/media_items/288)**

  > A ceasefire agreement between Israel and Egypt signed on 7 August 1970, putting an end to the War of Attrition, a period of low-intensity conflict along the Suez Canal since the conclusion of the 1967 Six Day War. The agreement made no changes to the territorial or military status quo.
- **[The Jarring Initiative - English Text (8 Feb, 1971)](https://ecf.org.il/media_items/540)**

  > A plan put forth by Swedish diplomat and UN Special Envoy Gunnar Jarring on 8 February 1971, aimed at de-escalating the tensions between Israel and Egypt following the conclusion of the War of Attrition, with a view towards implementing UN Security Council Resolution 242. Jarring proposed an Israeli withdrawal from the Sinai Peninsula and back to the 1906 international border, in return for demilitarization arrangements and guarantees for freedom of navigation through the Suez Canal and Straits of Tiran. In addition, Jarring requested both sides to uphold a state of non-belligerency (in lieu of a peace treaty) and to respect each other's independence and territorial integrity. Egypt consented to the plan in principle, provided demilitarization would be in equal distances, and Israel withdraws fully from both the Sinai Peninsula and the Gaza Strip. On its part, Israel proposed terms for a comprehensive peace agreement between the two countries, but rejected a withdrawal to the pre-1967 lines.
- **[The Third Rodgers Plan, 1971](https://ecf.org.il/issues/issue/151)**

  > A plan proposed by US Secretary of State William P. Rogers in a speech before the UN General Assembly on 4 October 1971. In light of difficulties in implementing UN Security Council Resolution 242 and reaching a comprehensive Arab-Israeli settlement, Rogers proposed an interim agreement to be signed between Egypt and Israel. This agreement would involve maintaining the ceasefire that ended the War of Attrition, allowing the Suez Canal to be reopened, redeploying Israeli forces east of the Canal and promoting an overall settlement. Though the initiative failed to prevent the 1973 War, a similar interim agreement was eventually signed in 1975, paving the road for the Israel-Egypt peace treaty.

Comment: The first two things I had found. I was looking for an official document about the Third Rodgers Plan, 1971.